# What is overflow: hidden doing in this code?

Tags: html, css, overflow

As I understand both overflow and div, things are not happening like I expect when I remove the overflow property here or set it to visible, nor do I understand why it does what it does when set to hidden as it is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:2;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I understand it, the divs are block elements which should mean that regardless of overflow property, the second div should begin automatically on the next line below the above div which makes the nav bar, but if I remove the overflow or set it to visible, that second div gets pushed up and sits on top of the nav bar.  This is really odd to me because from what I read about the overflow property, it is supposed to affect the elements of the div it specifies, not the div below it that it seemingly has nothing to do with.  Also, as far as I can tell, there is nothing that is overflowing for me to need to hide in the first place!

Comment: `overflow:hidden` also causes floated elements to push the boundary of the bottom of the element.

Comment: So every odd thing I'm asking about is coming from the fact that all the navbar's elements are being floated?

Comment: So I think I get most of this now.  If I set overflow to visible, the float left is causing the second div to begin right after the first one, to the right of it, instead of down a line.  But why does this also cause the black background of the link elements in the first div to disappear?

Comment: Toggle the `float:left` property of the child and you'll understand. Codename: ["The great collapse"](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-3). Also read the following section (clearing floats) - the overflow method.